# Why was org.apache.common.lang3 StringEscapeUtils deprecated?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

I couldn't find any explanation why StringEscapeUtils was deprecated from Apache Lang3 v3.7.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

What are we supposed to use now for HTML escaping/unescaping

Comment: It's right there in the link you posted: `Deprecated. 
as of 3.6, use commons-text StringEscapeUtils instead`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The class was moved from package

> org.apache.commons.<s>**lang3**</s>

to

> org.apache.commons.**text**

**You can  replace the deprecated library easily:**

In your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.11.0'
```

And in your class using `StringEscapeUtils` make sure you import the correct class:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
```

1.11.0 is currently the newest version (last checked February 20th 2024) but you can check the versions at maven:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text

Comment: @user3871754 No, it is deprecated in the org.apache.commons.lang3 as it was adopted here in org.apache.commons.text as you can read here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/index.html (it clearly states "This code has been adapted from Apache Commons Lang 3.5.")

Answer (score 16):

Per the [deprecation listing](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/deprecated-list.html), it was moved to a new project -- [commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)

Answer (score 13):

From [Commons-lang 3.6 release notes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/release-notes/RELEASE-NOTES-3.6.txt):

> The Apache Commons Community has recently set up the Commons Text component
>   as a home for algorithms working on strings. For this reason most of the string
>   focused functionality in Commons Lang has been deprecated and moved to
>   Commons Text. This includes:
>
> o All classes in the org.apache.commons.lang3.text and the
>       org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate packages
>   o org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
>   o org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils
>   o The methods org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance and
>       org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance
>
> For more information see the Commons Text website:
>
> ```
> http://commons.apache.org/text
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Do below steps

- Add below dependency to your pom.xml (if using maven)
  **<dependency>

             <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>

             <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>

             <version>1.4</version>

  <dependency>**
- Import correct package as below
  **import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;**
- There is no such method unescapeHtml() in this class anymore, instead its two 
  variations are available
  **unescapeHtml3() and unescapeHtml4()**
- Use unescapeHtml3() to unescape Html 3.0 characters
- Use unescapeHtml4() to unescape Html 4.0 characters

Comment: Latest version available now for this lib   <version>1.9</version>

Comment: Yes @VivekJain you are right, but at the time of posting my answer it was 1.4