# How to unescape xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, escaping, deprecated, stringescapeutils

Unfortunately all about this topic is too old, so i need a help.

How i can unescape xml in java? I tried `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml`
from
`import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;` but it's deprecated.
I also tried StringEscapeUtils as an object but there is only escapeHtml14
Next I tried answer from this [Why was org.apache.common.lang3 StringEscapeUtils deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817480/why-was-org-apache-common-lang3-stringescapeutils-deprecated) adding to maven, but it didn't work too.

Also tried
[image]

with adding

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to maven.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Replace `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;` by `import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commons text StringEscapeUtils it should work fine

`import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` have `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml();`

This is a build issue it is working in my system, I cross-checked in apache commons text [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/index.html)

[image]

Please clean install using maven and check.

Comment: I would like to but it's red. Picture added to question body.

Comment: which version of apache commons are you using? @TomášMejzr

Comment: Try running maven update and clean install.

Comment: Yes. After reload and multiple patches it works now. Thanks !